# What is the value of String.fromCharCode(8) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my program i'm using a function

```
String.fromCharCode(value)
```

On pressing backspace the value returned is 8.

```
String.fromCharCode(8)
```

The above returns a certain value which looks like an empty string but has a length 1.

What is it's actual value?

Comment: I'd guess it's a non printable character. Why does it matter?

Comment: It's the backspace character, which is not a printable character hence the appearance of an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 8 is the char code for Backspace. It wont result anything because Backspace has no display interpretation.

You can check the char codes here : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 1):

[String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) returns the unicode character of the unicode value you pass it. 8 is the unicode value for backspace, and it returns the backspace character (which is unprintable).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters